# Download a large zipped CSV file, unzip and read into R on Linux

Tags: r, linux, csv, unzip

I wish to read into my environment a large CSV (~ 8Gb) but I am having issues.

My data is a publicly available dataset:

```
# CREATE A TEMP FILE TO STORE THE DOWNLOADED DATA
temp <- tempfile()

# DOWNLOAD THE FILE FROM THE CMS
download.file("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_February_2022.zip",
              destfile = temp)
```

This is where I'm running into difficulty, I am unfamiliar with linux working directories and where temp folders are created.

When I use `list.dir()` or `list.files()` I don't see any reference to this temp file.

I am working in an R project and my working director is as follows:

```
getwd()
[1] "/home/myName/myProjectName"
```

I'm able to read in the first part of the file but my system crashes after about 4Gb.

```
# UNZIP THE NPI FILE
npi <- unz(temp, "npidata_pfile_20050523-20220213.csv")
```

I then came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42743886/5571686) post which has a function for decompressing large zip files using the system2 unzip functionality. However due to my limited R knowledge and Linux experience I couldn't get the function to point to the downloaded file in the temp folder

checking the path for `temp` above I get the following path:

```
temp
[1] "/tmp/Rtmpl6SHIJ/file7e5e6c1fc693"
```

Using the system2 function from the link above I tried the following:

```
x <- decompress_file(directory = temp,
                     file = "NPPES_Data_Dissemination_February_2022.zip")
```

But get the following error about setting the working directory:

[image]

Any pointers to how I can get this file unzipped given it's size and read it into memory would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might be a file permissions problem with `/tmp`. Can you download the file to `/home/myName/myProjectName` & decompress there instead?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does `/tmp` reside on it's own filesystem, and if yes, how big is it? :)

Comment: @mrhellmann thanks for the reply, I tried downloading to my project dir rather than the temp and I got a waring about "Warning messages:
1: In download.file("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_February_2022.zip",  :
  URL https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_February_2022.zip: cannot open destfile '/home/myName/myProjectName', reason 'Is a directory'"

Comment: @tink thanks for the reply, I am not sure if it's on a separate file system. Is there a linux command that I could use to check?

Comment: @TheGoat try `download.file("url from above", destfile = "/home/myName/myProjectName/npi.csv")` replace `url from above` with the actual url & destfile should be a full path with the filename you want.

Comment: `df -h | grep tmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a file permission issue.  To get around it work in a directory you're already in, or know you have access to.

```
# DOWNLOAD THE FILE 
# to a directory you can access, and name the file. No need to overcomplicate this.

download.file("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_February_2022.zip",
              destfile = "/home/myName/myProjectname/npi.csv")

# use the decompress function if you need to, though unzip might work
x <- decompress_file(directory = "/home/myName/myProjectname/",
                     file = "npi.zip")

# remove .zip file if you need the space back
file.remove("/home/myName/myProjectname/npi.zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is the path to the file, not just the directory. By default, `tempfile` does not add a file extension. It can be done by using `tempfile(fileext = ".zip")`

Consequently, `decompress_file` can not set the working directory to a file. Try this:

```
x <- decompress_file(directory = dirname(temp), file = basename(temp))
```